# Will a query with eager loading and lockForUpdate also lock the eager loaded rows?

Tags: mysql, laravel, innodb, eloquent

I'm using Laravel and eager loading an email table. With the following query, would it lock the email table along with the users table?

```
$queue = Users::with('email')
                ->lockForUpdate()
                ->get()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't: you can add `var_dump(DB::getQueryLog())` after your query to see all queries.
If you want to lock email table, you may try

```
$queue = Users::with(array('email'=>function($query){
            $query->lockForUpdate();
    })->lockForUpdate()
    ->get()
```